# Scale down an image if it's too big for the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html page where in the middle there is a pic.
Is there a way to scale down the image with javascript in case it's too big for the current monitor resolution?

I mean if a user with a resolution of 1600*1200 open an image of 1900*1200 the image should be scaled down to fit the window.

I can use jquery

Comment: Do you really mean "scroll down", or "scale down"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just use css?

```
.imgresize {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;        
}
```

Comment: Hmm I think this solution got a problem. If someone with an iphone/mobile opens this page, the image will be always scaled down to the max-width of the iphone... hmm =/

Comment: have you tried it? it will scale to 100% of the parent element. if you don't want it to scale on a small screen try using css media queries http://www.google.com/search?q=css+media+queries

Answer (score 1):

Look here: [Image resize to fit screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569192/jquery-javascript-image-resize-to-fit-screen)

else: http://jsfiddle.net/jsNDW/1/

HTML

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/1950x550" class="imgresize">
```

And JQUERY

```
var wWidth = $(window).width();
var wHeight = $(window).height();

$('.imgresize').each( function() {
var imgWidth = $(this).width();
var imgHeight = $(this).height();

    if(imgWidth >  wWidth)
    {
        $(this).width(wWidth);
    }

    if(imgHeight >  wHeight )
    {
        $(this).width(wHeight);
    }

});


$(window).resize(function() {
var wWidth = $(window).width();
var wHeight = $(window).height();

$('.imgresize').each( function() {
var imgWidth = $(this).width();
var imgHeight = $(this).height();

    if(imgWidth >  wWidth)
    {
        $(this).width(wWidth);
    }

    if(imgHeight >  wHeight )
    {
        $(this).height(wHeight);
    }

});

});
```

Comment: pretty nice even tho it doesn't scale up but i think this is easly fixable

Comment: Do you want it to be fullscreen if its smaller than the screen?

Comment: @dynamic All you need to do is handle the window resize event and it will scale up. For some reason, jQuery only responds to the view shrinking without explicit instruction.